# Унифицированная инициализация класса функтора или нет

Tags: c++, инициализация

Что здесь происходит? Похоже на унифицированную инициализацию, но каким образом этот функтор так неявно вызывается?
Реализация accumulate роли не играет, т.к. такое же поведение наблюдается при написании обычной "possible realisation".

```
    struct times{
    template<typename T>
    T operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const{return x*y;};
    };
    vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int res = accumulate(begin(v), end(v), 1, times{});
```

Comment: Вот я код понял, а вопрос - нет...

Comment: [здесь - это где](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGrTH.jpg)? Функтор явно вызывается в реализации `accumulate`, а не тут. Какое "такое" поведение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`times{}` - это [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) (именно при пустых скобках).

Между `times{}` и `times()` нет никакой разницы (опять же, именно при пустых скобках, и без учета возможного vexing parse во втором случае).

---

> каким образом этот функтор так неявно вызывается

Вот эту часть не понял. В вашем коде нет вызова функтора. Он вызывается в недрах `accumulate`, вполне явно.

Ваш код только создает объект-функтор типа `times` и передает его в функцию.

Comment: "В данном случае это просто вызов конструктора по умолчанию"... На самом деле нет. Если в классе нет *предоставленного пользователем* (user-provided) конструктора по умолчанию, то value-initialization приводит к zero-initialization (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#8.2). Конструктор в такой инициализации участия не принимает. В данном случае разницы никакой, но тем не менее.

Comment: @AnT Согласен, поправил.